# Low disk space: home/user folder occupies 94GB

Tags: 11.04, disk, disk-usage

I am low on disk space and when I check the Disk Usage analyzer (using `gksudo baobab`) it indicates that my home/teddy folder is using 94GB, but when I browse through its contents I can only account for about 1gb of that usage. I've tried `sudo apt-get clean` and deleting the cached package files from Synaptic Package Manager, emptied trash but that has not changed the amount of free space I have.

[image: Disk use]

It seems similar to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem)
But using the root disk usage analyzer has not given any insight into what is consuming so much space.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of baobab you may want to look at the tool "gdmap" - it shows space in a more visual way [you'll get a big rectangle for your big file]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think you have some gigantic files that disk analyzer is not seeing for some reason, you may use ls to look for large files. Try this for example:
 `ls -alrS` in your home folder.

Is this a wubi installatoin shared with win32 files? A few weeks ago I encountered a similar issue on a wubi system that was installed by a friend. As it is in your case, the disk analyzer was showing a really high value for home folder, much more than the sum of its sub-folders. I cant comment on why disk analyser was behaving in this way, but the approach I took in my case was to do a clean install of Ubuntu on a dedicated partition. Of course that is not a very good solution, but if this is a relatively new system, it might be a reasonable workaround.

Hopefully someone else can shed some light on why disk analyzer is behaving in this way, and how to make that disk space available.

Comment: Wow interesting. 'ls -alrs' shows a huge xsession file:

96838903975 2011-11-21 20:59 .xsession-errors.old

I deleted the file and now have 95gb free. Awesome, thank you for  showing me that command.

Comment: @tedtoy It seems absurd that a simple log file could grow that large. You should run `fsck` just in case this is an indication of something wrong with the filesystem structure.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like there is a very big file in /home/teddy. You can look for it either in Nautilus, checking view hidden files, list view and ordering by size, or from the command line:

```
du -a --max-depth=1 ~ | sort -n
```

The last entry before the home dir itself should be the biggest file.

---

du reports the file size of the first argument and all it's subdirs.

- -a makes it show all files and dirs
- --max-depth=1 keeps it from looking on all subdirs.

sort will sort the results

- -n they will be sorted numerically.

Comment: Thanks! That also shows the xsession-errors file, but in a slighty more readable format. Very useful ubuntu-fu, I will try and remember this one too.

Answer (score 0):

I was baffled by my disksystem all the same, telling me a **cp -r /home** would not work cause there is no space left (moving 840MB to a "2.9GB free" partitition).

The meat of the story is: du did not find a subdir "Öffentlich" and did not count the files inside it.

For those interested - thats what I found : 
du told me **840 MB used**  (Disk Usage analyzer the same)
df told me **5,3 GB used**

*I found various tips revolving around*

```
lsof -n | grab deleted    (to find out wether there are any "deleted yet open" files hugging space)

sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Block size'  (to find out the block size 4k in my case)
find /home -size -4k | wc -l    (to find out the number of files smaller than 1 block, a 10 bytes file using a 4046 block is wasting lots a space)

du -sh ./*   (finding the space used (real size) in each subdir)
df -i        (finding not the number of used blocks, but the no of used inodes, whats it worth for, I am not sure yet.)

Further tips found : 
Disk Usage Analyzer is rights-aware - "sudo baobab" will show more than "baobab"
du -c --max-depth=4 /dir | sort -n
ncdu utility found at: http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu
```

The best tip for me was **du -sh**. It helped me find following directory, which was not "cumulated" into the **du /**  sum.
    /home/mine/pictures/Öffentlich   (german O-Umlaut)

At first I thought that was for the "O-Umlaut", but copying /home to a new partition solved that for me.

Good luck hunting.

Answer (score -1):

because u install Ubuntu from windows wubi installation u choose the space u want in advance say 10 giga when u reach this space u will have low disk space even your drive is still have more memory ,as drive i mean the partition u install the release on it

in linux i prefer to install it from cd ,or from wubi with determine an enough space to ur relaese 
:D :D