# Why does the total space used on my hard drive not reflect what Disk Usage Analyzer Says?

Tags: disk, disk-usage, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is taking up so much space on my disk, beside the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem)

I'm a bit curious as to why my hard drive space, according to Disk Usage Analyzer, has 20 GB more used space than the space my files take up. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

On "/", it says that only 121.1 GB is used, but apparently 141.1 GB is used. I have 3 partitions on my HDD: a GRUB partition, my Ubuntu partition, and a 3 GB Swap Partition.

So, any thoughts? I really would like to know if I can make this 141.1 GB shrink to the 120 GB that it should be.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem   This question answers mine...I should have clicked this, but I never say it until after I asked it. I voted to close the question, please may others do the same? :)

Comment: @izx, whenever I either come upon a question that is a duplicate and/or have a duplicate question myself, should I both flag AND add that to the question?

Comment: No, I added that manually, it's only added automatically when a question is actually closed as a duplicate (by mod or on reaching 5 votes). Flagging it is sufficient; once you reach 2k rep, flagging will also automatically add the "Possible duplicate.." comment.