# Where did my free space go?

Tags: disk-usage, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is taking up so much space on my disk, beside the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem)

I have a storage drive (2TB) and an OS drive (90GB SSD).  I've run out of space on the OS drive:

```
/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        72G   72G     0 100% /
udev            5.9G   12K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G  1.2M  2.4G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G  428K  5.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1       1.9T  639G  1.2T  37% /media/StorageDrive
```

So be it.  But when I attempt to figure out where the space has gone, I cannot find it anything remotely approaching the capacity of the drive:

```
/$ sudo du -h -d 1
du: cannot access `./media/StorageDrive/home/ari/.gvfs': Permission denied
675G    ./media
2.3G    ./var
0   ./proc
7.0M    ./tmp
27M ./boot
4.0K    ./lib64
12K ./dev
44M ./home
16K ./lost+found
8.0M    ./sbin
223M    ./lib
4.0K    ./selinux
1.4M    ./run
140K    ./root
8.8M    ./bin
4.0K    ./mnt
38M ./etc
8.0K    ./srv
4.8G    ./usr
65M ./opt
0   ./sys
682G    .
```

Note the difference between the total (682G) and the mounted drives in /media (675G) is only about 9G.  How are 72G being used?  Where is this dark matter hiding?

Comment: Can't you use Baobab disk usage analyser to analyse it?

Comment: @DanialBehzadi Not sure why that would see any files that `du` is missing.  Indeed, it shows the same thing as `du`: there's no directory on `/` other than `/media` big enough to come close to filling the drive.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not a subdirectory causing problems, it's possible that there is a large file in / taking up space.   Please run the following to see if there's a likely culprit there:

```
sudo ls -al /
```

Comment: Good thought, but `sudo ls -al /` shows the largest file as `tmp` at 118784 bytes, then `etc` at 12288 bytes, then the rest all directories at 4096 bytes.  Odd that `tmp` and `etc` which are both directories aren't also 4096.  `lost+found` is 16384 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer, and unfortunately it's too localized to help anyone.  When I hooked my backup drive up to backup, it didn't mount it to the usual spot for some reason.  So a directory BackupDrive was created in /media (and thus on /dev/sdb1), which had filled up.  Epic fail.

Comment: lol - but hey, people will know not to make the same mistake!

Comment: @WindowsEscapist Ha, true.  But now I have to re-do my backup!

Comment: I'm confused. You mounted an external disk under `/media/xxx`. That shouldn't have affected the output of `df -h /dev/sdb1`, though. `df` only looks at one filesystem at a time, and it ignores where partitions have been mounted.

Comment: "BackupDrive" versus "StorageDrive"?

Comment: `df` was speaking true, as was `du`.  `du` showed me the usage for `/media` though, which I assumed was all `storagedrive` because the backup drive was unmounted.  In fact, though, it was `storagedrive` (mounted) plus a directory `backupdrive` (which was where the actual backup drive was supposed to get mounted, but hadn't been when the backup was made).