# How do I make sense of the Disk Usage Analyzer?

Tags: disk-usage

I got an alert on my desktop saying that my home directory had only 1.8 GB remaining, which seemed odd to me because I thought I had a lot more than that. I keep my `/home` directory on a separate partition with roughly 300GB, and I didn't think I had used that much.

There was a button to open the Disk Usage Analyzer, and this was what was displayed:

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer]

Two things confuse me.

1. It says I have `286.6 GB` total space, of which only `60.8 GB` is used, leaving `225.9 GB` available. That being the case, why does it say 100% usage in the list of directories?
2. Storage is on a separate partition, with a symlinked directory in my home folder. Why is it being included in the total? (It isn't more than 1/3 full in any case).

If I run Disk Usage Analyzer as root, which was suggested to me as being potentially more informative, I actually get a display that has less information and just as confusing:

[image: Root Disk Usage Analyzer]

Comment: You have to run it as root, which is explained in [this duplicate question](http://askubuntu.com/q/17467/12864).

Comment: @TomBrossman: Running the Disk Usage Analyzer as root does not lead to any more revealing information. In fact, it is even more terse and unrevealing than running it as a regular user. I've attached a screenshot to my question.

Comment: That's strange. I don't think I ever got meaningful results out of Disk Usage Analyzer (I'm probably using it wrong) but I've had better results with [GdMap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GdMap). Failing that, make sure that you've scanned the drive (it looks like the second screenshot shows the program waiting for you to tell it where to scan...).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It says I have 286.6 GB total space, of which only 60.8 GB is used, leaving 225.9 GB available. That being the case, why does it say 100% usage in the list of directories?

You have obviously chosen to scan your home directory. What is shown is *what folders make up the total of the home directory*, and hence all the contents of the home directory will add up to 100%. As a clarification, it is shown that *the home directory contains 100% of the listed directories and files*.

> 1. Storage is on a separate partition, with a symlinked directory in my home folder. Why is it being included in the total? (It isn't more than 1/3 full in any case).

This might indeed make it a bit hard to interpret the figures. What I do know is that the program *will follow symlinks*. As to my knowledge, this can't be disabled.

I am not sure from where the program will get the "Total filesystem capacity" data at the top when several filesystems are in play on the scanned path through symlinks.

For a clearer view on the file system capacity (capacities), it might be more useful to use the `df` terminal command. Run with an option, `df -h`to get human readable file sizes. The command will list the physical drives and the mount points, e.g.:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5                158G   51G   99G  34% /
none                     4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                     1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                    386M  1,2M  385M   1% /run
none                     5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                     1,9G  1,5M  1,9G   1% /run/shm
none                     100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
deskt:/media/Samsung     801G  414G  388G  52% /mnt/deskt/data
deskt:/home/carl         113G   40G   68G  37% /mnt/deskt/carl
deskt:/tmp               113G   40G   68G  37% /mnt/deskt/tmp
/dev/sda3                 63G   26G   37G  42% /media/carl/OS
```

The `/dev/sda?` entries will show the capacity and usage of the different partitions.

On a side note, a more natural approach of having the home folder on a separate partition would be to mount /home/ to that partition, rather than doing it with a symlink.

Comment: I agree with the answer that was deleted. That a program called "*Disk* Usage Analyzer" is giving me results based on a particular directory's contents is counter intuitive.