# How do I completely remove/uninstall an application?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, uninstall

I need to remove Pitivi video editor and Cinelerra and a few more applications, I have seen people talking about how to uninstall something completely but the problem is that I don't even know the "name" of my applications. When I say "name", I mean the name that I could put in the terminal to run/install/remove them. Please help me, my computer is running out of disk space.

Comment: I think you mean` cinelerra` instead of `cinerella`?

Comment: Well yeah probably

Comment: Related: [What is taking up so much space on my disk, beside the filesystem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `apt-cache search KEYWORDS` to search for the package name which contains KEYWORDS in its description.

You can also use `dpkg -l PACKAGENAME` to list all *installed* packages that match the pattern PACKAGENAME. You can use `?` (one arbitrary character) and `*` (any number of arbitrary characters) as wildcards.

Then use `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge PACKAGE` to remove PACKAGE completely, including configuration and all no longer needed dependencies.

**Example for PiTiVi:**

- Find out the package name:

  ```
  $ apt-cache search PiTiVi
  pitivi - non-linear audio/video editor using GStreamer
  ```
- Purge the package and its dependencies:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pitivi
  [...some output...]
  ```

Comment: Ok thanks! And by the way do you know what happened to my minecraft? I can't do anything on servers I used to use java 7 now I switched to java 8 and a lot of things go wrong in singleplayer but in multiplayer things go better :/

Comment: @EmilyShan Sorry, but I don't use Minecraft, so I can't help you there. However I think I've heard that they recommend the Oracle implementation and not the OpenJDK implementation. Maybe that makes a difference... But you should ask a new question about that issue, nobody will notice it if you place it in a comment here. Also, if my answer helped you and solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of it. You can learn the most important things about how this site works on our small [tour] page if you haven't done this already. Thanks!

Comment: Oh ok, it's all right. And by the way, what is the difference between the up arrow and the check? I always forget it sorry. And thanks a lot for the commands they worked!{for me, since I'm horrible with computers, almost nothing works(Idk how to use them)}

Comment: By the way, for cinelerra, how do I find out the package name? When I go to applications then sound and videos then it says Cinelerra-CV, when I put "apt-cache search cinelerra-cv" it says "cinelerra-cv - Non-linear audio/video authoring tool"

Comment: You can also use `dpkg -l PACKAGENAME` to list all *installed* packages that match the pattern PACKAGENAME. You can use `?` (one arbitrary character) and `*` (any number of arbitrary characters) as wildcards. In your case, I would try e.g. `dpkg -l cine*` or `dpkg -l cinelerra*`.