# Problem with conky and Disk usage

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, disk-usage, conky

I hope that the title is clear. I have this problem:
With `Disk Usage Analyzer` I have this situation

[image]

As we can see the /home/linofex directory uses about 6 GB.
Well, I wrote these lines in a conky script:

```
 Root ${fs_used /} $color/ ${fs_size /}
 home ${fs_used /home/linofex} $color/ ${fs_size /home/linofex}
 data ${fs_used /media/ntfs} $color/ ${fs_size /media/ntfs}
```

But conky shows:

[image]

where data is an other partition and Root is `${fs_used /} $color/ ${fs_size /}`

Why the numbers of GB doesn't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem reading this [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem?rq=1).
Running Disk Usage Disk with superuser privileges I saw that there was `.Trash-0` directory with a lot of junk (the 14 - 6 GB) that I couldn't delete without be root. With `sudo rm -r .Trash-0/` I solved and now all work good.