# My main hard drive on ubuntu has no free space left

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, hardware

I have a hard drive that keeps filling up with data, but I'm unable to figure out what is causing it. 
I tried moving files, but the system just replaces that data with more useless data. This made it tough for me to install anything on my drive.

As soon as I restart my computer after removing files, the info box says:

> Free space: 0 bytes

I've even freed a gig of data on my hard drive but it still goes back to reducing my free space down to zero. I've looked all over the place, but I couldn't find anything useful that I could use to help me.
Disks is telling me that File Partition 6 74 GB Ext 4 is completely full. File Partition 6 Ext 4 is my Root and Home partition. Unfortunately I'm unable to send a screen shot of the program because I can't open my web browser at the moment, so I'm using my Windows laptop to report the problem.
My current Linux system is Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is taking up so much space on my disk, beside the filesystem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem)

Comment: Try `ls -lh /var/log/uvcydnctrl-udev.log`. If the file is there, it's probably huge, and you can safely remove it with `sudo rm /var/log/uvcdynctrl-udev.log`.

Comment: It tells me `ls: cannot access '/var/log/uvcydnctrl-udev.log' : No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it may be obvious but have you cleaned out your old images? The old superseded ones do stick around and they do take up space.
Fire up synaptic and search for "linux-image" and click on **installed**. If you have a loooooong list of images with ascending numbers you need to delete all but the ones with numbers lower than the last two with the highest number.
It was this that forced me to re-install before I got Ubuntu Tweak; http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-tweak-ubuntu.html which does this is a more noob friendly GUI sort of way.

Comment: Htop is telling me that have tons of duplicates of my programs. It might be that. However, Ubuntu tweak isn't available for my version of Linux (Xubuntu 16.04 LTS)