# Amazon EC2 instance Ubuntu 16.04 : Cannot create temp file for here document. No space left on device

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, amazon-ec2, memory-usage

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04, which keeps on running out of memory killing my mongod process in turn.

Doing `df -h` gives

```
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   41M  355M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.4G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

so as my `/dev/xvda1` is full. I go in my '/' or root directory and do a

```
ls -l --block-size=M 
total 1M
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Nov 22 04:49 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 1M Dec 21 13:14 boot
drwxrw-rwx   3 root root 1M Oct 18 21:01 data
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 1M Oct 18 20:30 dev
drwxr-xr-x  91 root root 1M Dec 14 01:29 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 1M Oct 18 20:30 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 1M Dec 21 13:14 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 1M Dec  6 05:03 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root 1M Sep  7 19:24 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Sep  7 19:22 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 1M Sep  7 19:26 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Sep  7 19:22 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Sep  7 19:22 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Sep  7 19:22 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 139 root root 0M Oct 18 20:29 proc
drwx------   4 root root 1M Oct 18 21:00 root
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 1M Dec 25 13:55 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Oct 19 06:11 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Sep  1 17:37 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 1M Sep  7 19:22 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root 0M Dec 25 13:59 sys
drwxrwxrwt  11 root root 1M Dec 25 14:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 1M Sep  7 19:22 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root 1M Oct 18 20:52 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 1M Dec 21 13:14 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 1M Dec  6 05:03 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
```

If I add up all the file size it doesn't add up to be 7.4 GB. Then what is ? and how do I fix this? So that it doesn't overflow and kill my mongod process in return.

On some of the answer. It said restart your system. Post restarting this is the output.

```
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M  5.6M  390M   2% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.3G  2.2G  72% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I still use 5.3G of space. what is causing 2 GB to be filled? How do I drill down the issue?

**Latest Edit**
After starting 2 NodeJS process and a mongod process post restart. In less than 14 hrs it again off memory.

**NOT A DUPLICATE**
They were running a local instance of Ubuntu and I am not. The answer which helps drill down the cause, will not run here. It was stopped with error `(gksudo:3647): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`. Most of the answers here require somekind of GUI based tools. Which is a limitation here. Hence this is not a duplicate and I request it to be kept open.

**EDIT 1**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-235:/$ sudo du -hcsx .[!.]* * | sort -rh | head
du: cannot access '.[!.]*': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4433/task/4433/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4433/task/4433/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4433/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/4433/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
3.9G    total
1.8G    usr
983M    home
363M    lib
323M    data
249M    var
163M    boot
16M bin
13M sbin
5.8M    etc
```

If 3.9 GB is totally utilized.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-235:/$ df -h                                   
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M  5.6M  390M   2% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  6.5G  936M  88% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

and Used is 6.5 GB where did 2.6 GB go?

**EDIT 2**
Adding output of sudo lsof | grep deleted

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-235:/$ sudo lsof | grep deleted
mongod    1272                ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1273           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1275           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1276           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1277           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1278           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1279           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1280           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1281           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1282           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1283           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1284           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1285           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1286           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1287           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1288           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1289           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1291           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1292           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1293           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1294           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1297           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1298           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1299           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1300           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1301           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1302           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1303           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1304           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1305           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1306           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1307           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1308           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1309           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1310           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1311           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1312           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1313           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1314           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1315           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1316           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1317           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1318           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1319           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1320           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1321           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1322           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1323           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1324           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1325           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1326           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1327           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1328           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1329           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1330           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1331           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1332           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1333           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1334           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1335           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1336           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1337           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1338           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1342           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 1753           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 2499           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
mongod    1272 2500           ubuntu    4w      REG              202,1 2727852655     160748 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (deleted)
```

Comment: @muru it's not I edited the question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/740648/158442 does not.

Comment: It doesn't help exactly. Please check the Edit

Comment: Could there be a running process holding a reference to a large unlinked file – like a database instance or a large log file with many repetitive messages? Those won't show up in `du` but they still occupy space until the process closes the file descriptor (process termination, maybe forceful, will achieve that too).

Comment: @SarasArya also add the output of `sudo lsof | grep deleted`

Comment: @DavidFoerster how to do I get to the point of identifying such processes/files so I can close them down?

Comment: @muru Done that.

Comment: SarasArya there's the files @David hinted at. All those deleted files are still taking up space because mongod hasn't let go of them.

Comment: How do I permanently delete them and make sure that they don't reappear? Probably that could be written as an answer. Will appreciate it

Comment: @DavidFoerster How do I access these deleted files ? and how do I delete them permanently?

Answer (score 1):

According to the output of `lsof` there is a large (2.7 GB), unlinked (“`deleted`”) file that was once opened through the path `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`.

The only way to trigger the deletion of a file is to remove all references to it. That includes

- unlinking all its directory entries (which you did) ***and***
- closing all file descriptors referring to it.

Only the process holding the file descriptor can close it; alternatively the kernel closes all remaining file descriptors when a process terminates or is terminated. Since the file in question is is the log file of and its descriptor held by the `mongod` service the best way to achieve that is to terminate the service (e. g. with `sudo service mongod stop` or, if the daemon process is unresponsive, with `sudo killall -s KILL mongod`).

*This will not prevent the reoccurrence of the issue if the log file keeps getting filled. You need to look at the log content and investigate the issue of which `mongod` is trying to notify.* Please [open a new question](/questions/ask) if you need help with that.