# Visualize sorted storage volume use

Tags: files, partitioning, storage, sort

My desktop storage capacity reaches its limit.

How can I visualize my storage partition between files and apps (Android-like) to efficiently dig into the heaviest files?

Comment: Try look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, including `du`. A common graphical tool you can use is [Baobab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab).

Comment: Another way to make use of [Baobab] is to open your terminal and type `gksudo baobab`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use this command line :

```
du -sh /home/user/*
```

The result show you the different children with the used space disk.
You can of course changer the path with what you want to scan (/var, /opt, ...)