# Disk usage analyzer report different free space than terminal

Tags: 18.04, disk, disk-usage, df

I got an error that I'm running out of disk space while syncing dropbox, so I had to  delete some files. The strange thing is that the "disk usage analyzer" reported that I had about 15GB free space.

After deleting some data I used the command "df -lh" in the terminal, and here both the size of the volume, and the free space is different than in the disk usage analyzer. Currently I have 46.5GB out of 263.8GB free space reported from the disk usage analyzer. From the terminal, I get 31GB out of 246GB free space. Why are these different?

Answer (score 3):

Try running disk usage analyzer as sudo -- open your terminal and run:

```
sudo baobab
```

(apparently that's the machine name of disk usage analyzer)

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem/17559#17559)

**EDIT:**
Inconsistencies between what DUA shows and what terminal shows seem to be a known (albeit annoying) "quirk".  [The thread I mentioned above](https://askubuntu.com/a/17652/239856), and its accepted answer, indicate that significant inconsistencies are commonly due to sudo/non-sudo access, but also can be due to how DUA analyzes system folders, and mounted devices.  The asker/answerer on that thread mentions unmounting certain mounted devices.  [Section 5 of this Ubuntu Forums tutorial](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1122670) explains that DUA only reports on mounted devices. (...and, section 7 of ^^that tutorial has additional comments about reporting inconsistencies.)

Comment: Didn't make any difference to the result

Comment: made a difference for me.  thank you

Comment: [The thread I linked to earlier](https://askubuntu.com/a/17652/239856) (and the accepted answer over there) mentions inconsistencies between what terminal shows and what DUA shows -- it seems to be a known (albeit annoying) "quirk".  Some folks suggest unmounting all mounted things and checking again: [section 5 of this howto explains that DUA only reports on mounted devices](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1122670).

(Sorry for the belated response; I hope this helps whoever might end up on this thread in the future! -- I'll update my answer, too.)