# "Missing" around 300gb on 512gb ssd

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, disk-usage

I picked up a new laptop just recently and installed Ubuntu Mate 18.04 right away. So, the system is pretty clean.

That being said, here's the problem. I have got some disk space missing. I have got only one 512gb ssd with one partition. The system says I've got only a few gb of free space left. Disk Utility says the whole 512 gb are allocated.
Disk analyzer (baobab) shows me the following picture even though I am running it under root:

[image]

Do you guys have any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Home partition shows as 457 GB out of 512 GB -- doesn't look like you're "missing" any 300 GB, you just have files you can't account for.

Comment: @ZeissIkon well, yeah. But if so, how can I access them? And how come there's been 300gb worth of data somehow procedurally generated (?) on a clean system over a week or so.

Comment: I'd start by examining /home/Denis with "view hidden" turned on.

Comment: No expert, but usually with these type of questions, it is sometimes wonky log files taken up space.  link  https://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem?rq=1

Comment: @ZeissIkon it's the same as what baobab shows

Comment: Could also be a "counterfeit" or failing SSD.  Not uncommon for off-brand flash storage to report an incorrect capacity.  Have you run a full fsck scan?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I have not, but I will. Good idea.

Comment: Start with `ls -al` or `ls -alh` command in your home folder and look for big files.

Comment: Thanks guys, i figured it out. Turns out it's been a huge .xsession log file and for some reason baobab wasn't displaying it.